# Time reversal symmetry of scalar field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

Can anyone prove the time-reversal invariance of the following scalar field theory?
$$ \mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi-\frac{\mu^{2}}{2} \phi^{2}-g\phi\psi^*\psi+\partial_{\mu} \psi \partial^{\mu} \psi^*-m^2\psi^*\psi$$

Comment: What, specifically, are you stuck on?

Comment: my intuition goes as follows: the equation of motion for $\phi$ will be $$(\Box^2+\mu^2)\phi=-g\psi^*\psi$$and $T:\phi\rightarrow\phi(x,-t)$ and $T:\psi\rightarrow\psi(x,-t)$. Thus $\phi(x,-t)$ follows the same E.O.M, hence T is a symmetry. Am I right?

Comment: yes, but what about the operators?

Comment: you mean $a_p,a_p^\dagger$? wont they become $a_{-p},a_{-p}^\dagger$, then using the fourier expansion we will precisely get the same results. Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: The time derivatives are the only ones that are affected by the change in sign, and because they come in pairs, the sign cancels.

Comment: Time derivative in the equation of motion or in the Lagrangian?

Comment: In the Lagrangian.

Comment: ok. Can we say the same thing by looking at the equation of motion, i.e E.O.M does not have any odd order time derivative hence time reversal invariance?